# Is there one function I can call to parse any string into the appropriate JS Temporal type?

Tags: javascript, date-parsing, datetime-parsing, ecmascript-temporal

I've got a list of ISO 8601-compatible strings, some of which are dates (like `'2022-12-25'`), some are date-time values (like `'2022-12-25T12:00'`), and some have time zone info (like `'2022-12-25T12:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]'`.

Using the new [`Temporal`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) API that's coming to JavaScript, is there one function I can call to parse all these strings into their corresponding `Temporal` types like `Temporal.PlainDate`, `Temporal.PlainDateTime`, `Temporal.ZonedDateTime`, etc.?

Comment: No, that would be a very unusual API.

Comment: I agree!  We've actually had quite a few requests for this during the design process of the Temporal API. So I wanted to post a Q&A pair here to help future developers having the same question to explain why a universal parsing function is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a universal parse-into-any-`Temporal`-type function that's built into the language.

This is because the same string can be used to parse many different `Temporal` types.
To parse a string into a `Temporal` type, you must know ahead of time what type you want.

For example, `2020-04-25[u-ca=hebrew]` can be successfully parsed by `Temporal.PlainDate.from`, `Temporal.PlainMonthDay.from`, `Temporal.PlainYearMonth.from`, or even `Temporal.PlainDateTime.from`.
This ambiguity requires choosing a `Temporal` type before parsing.